# How to place <div> over floating image?

Tags: jquery, html, css-float

I need to place zoom icons over site images. Some of images have float=left or float=right style. I can use jQuery, this is an example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nvbe/1/

My current code:

`$("a[rel^='lightbox']").each(function () {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="zoom"></div>');
});`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qNQhx/

how about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to position the icons absolutely (position: absolute) and then use top, left and/or right properties to position them on the right spot over the image. Use position:relatvie in the wrapping (image) element to prevent the icons to position out of the image scope.